# group on some rules for a dimension in pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

The data looks as below:

```
datas = [
    ['/page_1', 1],
    ['/page_1?x=123', 2],
    ['/page_1/subpage_1', 1],
    ['/page_2', 10],
]
```

What I intend to do is to apply a custom groupby operation on it such that the result should be:

```
datas = [
    ['/page_1', 4],
    ['/page_2', 10],
]
```

How should I do it effectively via merely Python itself, or conveniently implemented it via Pandas?

Thanks tons.

Even more, it could be grouped-by on 2 dimensions like below:

```
#-- raw data
datas = [
    ['/page_1', 'China', 1],
    ['/page_1?x=123', 'China', 2],
    ['/page_1/subpage_1', 'US', 1],
    ['/page_2', 'Britain', 10],
]

#-- expected result
datas = [
    ['/page_1', 'China', 3],
    ['/page_1', 'US', 1],
    ['/page_2', 'Britain', 10],
]
```

I've already implemented a scenario for the 1-dimension groupby:

```
def mergeRowWithSameSuffix(datas):
    curPrefix = None
    curPrefixPV = 0
    curPrefixUV = 0

    rtn = []

    for data in datas:
        pagePathLevel2 = data[0].encode('utf-8').replace("'", "")
        pv = int(data[1])
        uv = int(data[2])

        if not curPrefix:
            curPrefix = pagePathLevel2
            curPrefixPV = pv
            curPrefixUV = uv
        elif pagePathLevel2.startswith(curPrefix+"?") or pagePathLevel2.startswith(curPrefix+"/"):
            curPrefixPV += pv
            curPrefixUV += uv
        else:
            rtn.append([curPrefix, curPrefixPV, curPrefixUV])
            curPrefix = pagePathLevel2
            curPrefixPV = pv
            curPrefixUV = uv

    rtn.append([curPrefix, curPrefixPV, curPrefixUV])

    return rtn
```

But this is not gonna work for 2-dimension groupby obviously. So I think there must be some way to implement it via Pandas.

Comment: Can you show your efforts so we can understand where you're stuck thanks

Comment: You could use the first section of the url as a key for a dictionary, and then then add your values to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of pandas dataframe methods and using regular expressions to pull out the root of the page information should do the trick.

```
# Do imports
import re
import pandas as pd

# Define regular expression to pull out root
xpr = re.compile('/([^/?]+)')
# Define initial dataframe, assuming your 3-column example above
df = pd.DataFrame(datas,columns=['Page','Country','Count'])
# Create a column for the root of the page column by applying a regular expression
df['Root'] = df['Page'].apply(lambda v:re.match(xpr,v).groups(0)[0])

# At this point, dataframe looks like:
#                 Page  Country  Count    Root
# 0            /page_1    China      1  page_1
# 1      /page_1?x=123    China      2  page_1
# 2  /page_1/subpage_1       US      1  page_1
# 3            /page_2  Britain     10  page_2

# Sum over the Root & Country groups
results = df.groupby(['Root','Country']).sum()
#                 Count
# Root   Country       
# page_1 China        3
#        US           1
# page_2 Britain     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting columns with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) if length of chars to `?` or `/` is equal:

```
print df.iloc[:,0].str[:7]
0    /page_1
1    /page_1
2    /page_1
3    /page_2
Name: 0, dtype: object

print df.groupby(df.iloc[:,0].str[:7]).sum().reset_index()
         0   1
0  /page_1   4
1  /page_2  10
```

Or:

```
print df.groupby([df.iloc[:,0].str[:7], df.iloc[:,1]]).sum().reset_index()
         0        1   2
0  /page_1    China   3
1  /page_1       US   1
2  /page_2  Britain  10
```

If length is not equal use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting columns with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
print df
                   0        1   2
0         /paaaage_1    China   1
1   /paaaage_1?x=123    China   2
2  /page_1/subpage_1       US   1
3            /page_2  Britain  10

xpr = re.compile('/([^/?]+)')
print df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(xpr)
0    paaaage_1
1    paaaage_1
2       page_1
3       page_2

print df.groupby([df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(xpr), df.iloc[:,1]]).sum().reset_index()
           0        1   2
0  paaaage_1    China   3
1     page_1       US   1
2     page_2  Britain  10
```